# AppResources - error CS0103: The name 'AppResources' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

In my Xamarin.Forms, **.NET standard Shared Project**, this was working well till I've changed the **target version to 2.0 from 1.4**

```
        private bool IsFirstLaunch()
        {
            return !Application.Current.Properties.ContainsKey(AppResources.Key_AppLaunchedForFirstTime);
       }
```

Everything compiles well, but I get a run-time error CS0103: The name **'AppResources' does not exist in the current context**

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I'm sorry, I haven't gone through all of the migration steps in the https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/under-the-hood/net-standard/

Comment: Use namespace UsingResxLocalization.Resx.AppResources